# c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error:

Tags: ubuntu, g++

I was trying make a file and got this error. I am a newbie. Can any one help me here.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++
standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be
enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

How to enable with `-std=c++0x`?
I used this in my makefile `#CXX_VERSION_FLAG = -std=c++0x` but did not work.

Thanks,
Addy

Comment: Remove the `#` at the start of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just pass these flags (aka options) to the compiler.  Instead of running `gcc ...`, run `gcc -std=c++0x ...` (or `-std=c++11` for newer compilers).

Answer (score 1):

Lines in Makefiles that start with '#' are comment lines.
Try removing the '#'.

Comment: Razeh, I just copied here after commenting out this line. But thanks.